# Regarding python (Used in many coding languages)

Tags: python, function, variables

Hey guys real noob question here,

```
def get_gender(sex = 'Unknown'): 
if sex is 'm':
    sex = "Male"
elif sex is 'f':
    sex = "Female"
print(sex)
```

The code above is a simple program from one of The New Boston's tutorials, I've seen in many different places this particular piece of code `def get_gender(sex = 'Unknown'):` used (Not the actual code itself but how it's used ie: `(sex = 'Unknown'):`) before but not too clear on how to use it in my own programs. I'm just wondering if someone is able to give me a run down of why this particular variable is in the brackets next to get_gender, what is it used for, is it any different than declaring the variable inside the function and maybe a few examples of ways it can be used.

I hope this makes sense and I have the utomost gratitude to any help.
Thank you

Comment: Indentation errors aside, the sex='Unknown' sets a default value if no sex is passed to the function, i.e. it is invoked without parameters: get_gender()

Comment: `(sex = 'Unknown')` means that argument `sex` in function is optional. Read docs about [Keyword Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is called [default argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument) It means that a caller may not chose to pass the particular parameter (for eg: `sex` in your case). The function will use the default value (`sex = unknown` in your case) if the parameter is not passed by the caller.

The most common use case of this pattern is when a function will tend to be called with a particular value most of the times.

For eg. [find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) in python has two default arguments `start` and `end`.

The library designers considered that a common usage pattern for `find` would be searching the entire string for a particular `string`. So the default values of `start` and `end` are `0` and `len(string)`

Some languages also provide this functionality via [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). So you create two functions with `find(substring, start, end)` and `find(substring)`. The latter can internally call the former as `find(substring, 0, length)`

Note some people [prefer function overloading over default argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182135.aspx)